# Creating WiX Installer with UI and Localization

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I have the requirement to create an installer for a WPF application. That's not much of a problem (but much of a pain with WiX), but now my client updated his requirements and I'm starting to get frustrated. Please tell me if the requested functionality is possible with WiX (and if, could you please provide a hint?).

**My Setup:**

- Visual Studio 2013
- WPF Application (many files as it includes a self hosted web server and some pages/css/js, etc)

**Requirements:**

- Installer has to be a MSI package for automated installation
- There has to be a UI guiding the user through the installation (where to install)
- The installer has to be localized (13 languages), starting with the windows language with the opportunity to change on installation
- The successfully installed app has to be started (or at least there should be the opportunity to do so at the end of the installation)

I'm not sure if it's even possible to create a functioning MSI with WiX Bootstraper. I've only seen exe files.

Thank's for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben,

It's a very easy task. Don't get frustrated. So here are solutions for your requirements. Hope you are still working on it :

- **Installer has to be a MSI package for automated installation**
  No need to add Bootstrapper for it. Just create a simple WiX installer.
- **There has to be a UI guiding the user through the installation (where to install)**
  You need to add WixUI.wixlib library in your project reference.
- **The installer has to be localized (13 languages), starting with the windows language with the opportunity to change on installation.**
  You need to add Languages in Package node.

  Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Languages="1033,1031"
- **The successfully installed app has to be started (or at least there should be the opportunity to do so at the end of the installation)**
  You need to write CustomAction for that & need to launch it after installation.

You can find a sample code [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html).

Comment: Hi Ajit! I'm sorry I missed your answer. You did it, I've fixed (nearly) all my issues! **Thank you!** The only part I'm having trouble with is the localization. Just adding the language codes results in an english only installer (just like not declaring them). Do you have an example utilizing Visual Studio?

Comment: You can add different languages support as well. I didn't get your next question of Visual Studio. Can you please make it clear ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mae it clear. Most of the examples for WiX are using command line creation (or I'm just understanding it wrong). I'm creating my setup in a visual studio project (right click -> create). 

I have no clue how I should follow the process of candle and light (who created all those names?) to create a single msi file with multiple languages.